# multiple interactive matplotlib behave differently in python 2.7 vs 3.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I have a python script that loops continuously with user input directing it to get data from a file then plots it using matplotlib. My hope is to have the plots show up and stick around (and continue to be interactive) while the script continues on in the console asking for the next round of user input and plotting. So the user might end up with a few plot windows open in the end that are all functional.

I actually have it working in my python 2.7 anaconda build with the following example code that just plots a random dataset each loop.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

print('matplotlib version: '+matplotlib.__version__)
version = sys.version_info[0]

def plot_data(data):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.001)

while True:
    if version < 3:
        option = raw_input('type (1) to plot next data, (q) to quit\n')
    else:
        option = input('type (1) to plot next data, (q) to quit\n')
    if option == '1':
        data = np.random.choice(1000,100, replace = False)
        plot_data(data)
    elif option == 'q':
        break
```

Running the code with my python 3.6 build, the plot shows up but is frozen in a non-responding state until I go back to the console and type in q to quit my user input loop. In python 2.7 the plot windows are fully functional through multiple input loops and plot calls. So I'm hoping someone knows what difference here. I'm printing the matplotlib version and it seems like both my 2.7 and 3.6 environments are using the same matplotlib 2.0.2 so maybe it's in the GUI handler?

Comment: I guess you would benefit from providing a [mcve] of the issue that allows people to test the program. Also clearly state the matplotlib versions in use and how you run this script.

Comment: OK i updated my question with working code that mimics my issue.

Comment: Does 'anaconda' alter anything on the way matplolib is imported? Can you run 'anaconda' with python 3?

Comment: both my python version builds are Anaconda. I can run the above .py file on either version by choosing the python.exe file that lives in the folder of each of my builds.

Comment: Well, I can't run the script, on either version of python on my computer, without having the plot frozen.

Comment: Correction, I can run 'correctly' the plots in python 2 but not on python 3. (Can't edit previous comment).

Comment: Right, same issue as me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the setup from the question using a while loop and `plt.ion()` is actually supposed to work. At least for me using python 2.7 and matplotlib 2.1 it doesn't.
I would have though that this is to be expected, because the application freezes and becomes unresponsive as long as it waits for user input.

In any case, since it is always a bit delicate to mix the console and a GUI application, I would choose to work completely inside the event loop of the GUI.

You may connect `"key_press_event"`s to the `"1"` and `"q"` key and show new data inside the open matplotlib window.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

def plot_data(ax, data):
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(data)
    ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

def press(event=None):
    if event:
        if event.key == "1":
            data = np.random.choice(1000,100, replace = False)
            plot_data(ax, data)
        elif event.key == "q":
            plt.close()

cid= fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", press)
plt.show()
```

In case you want to create several figures, this would look like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def create_figure(data):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
    ax.plot(data)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", press)
    fig.show()

def plot_data():
    data = np.random.choice(1000,100, replace = False)
    create_figure(data)

def press(event=None):
    if event:
        if event.key == "1":
            plot_data()
        elif event.key == "q":
            plt.close("all")
    else:
        plot_data()

press()
plt.show()
```

For more complicated input, you may create a small GUI, which collects the input and calls the function for plotting. As an example, one may use Tkinter for that purpose.

```
from Tkinter import * # use from tkinter import *  if using python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def create_figure(data):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
    ax.plot(data)
    fig.show()

def plot_data(n, amp):
    try:
        n = int(n)
        amp = float(amp)
        data = amp*np.random.rand(n)
        create_figure(data)
    except:
        pass

def closeall():
    for i in plt.get_fignums():
        plt.close(i)

def create_input():
    root = Tk()
    Label(text="Number of datapoints").grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=W)
    Label(text="Amplitude").grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=W)
    tb1=Entry(root,textvariable=StringVar(root, value='24'))
    tb1.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W+E)
    tb2=Entry(root,textvariable=StringVar(root, value='6'))
    tb2.grid(row=2,column=1, sticky=W+E)
    b1=Button(root,text="   Plot   ",command= lambda : plot_data(tb1.get(),tb2.get()))
    b1.grid(row=4,column=1, sticky=W+E)
    b2=Button(root,text="Close All",command=closeall)
    b2.grid(row=5,column=1, sticky=W+E)
    root.mainloop()

create_input()
```

[image]

Comment: The goal of my script is to allow multiple plot windows to be open and interactive at the same time. I do not want to update the data of a given plot window. Can you think of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear to me. I updated the answer.

Comment: OK that does work in 3.6 but in my real application, I need the user to input a few pieces of information in the terminal for the program to find and load the next dataset of their choosing. Can you help me integrate multiple functioning plots with simultaneous terminal input? Thanks

Comment: No, as said in the question: As I see it, terminal input will freeze the plotting window - I hence would not know how to do that.

Comment: Right but it only does it in python 3.6, not 2.7 for me. Any ideas on why?

Comment: No, because it also does it for me on python 2.7.

Comment: You may use a little GUI for the input parameters. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: yeah I've switch to tkinter gui for all the input, it seems to work great this way.